# How to exactly reproduce historical ORS-Isochrones?

Tags: r, ggmap, osrm, travel-time

During the reproduction of historical isochrones created with the API of [ORS - openrouteservice.org](http://openrouteservice.org), I ran into issues with the resolution. About 3 years ago, the returned isochrones had higher resolution than today and there is no option to manipulate any kind of resolution-parameter (as far as I know).

**ORS historical (3 years ago): higher resolution**
[image]

**ORS today: lower resolution**

```
library(leaflet)
library(openrouteservice)
coords <- c(9.4619375, 47.4776429)

isochrone_ors <- ors_isochrones(coords, range = 11*60)
leaflet() %>% 
  addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.TonerLite, group = "Toner Lite") %>% 
  addGeoJSON(geojson = isochrone_ors) %>% 
  fitBBox(isochrone_ors$bbox)
```

[image]

**OSRM: today**

I tried to reproduce the isochrones using `osrm::osrmIsochrone()`. Unfortunately this osrm implementation generates sqare-cut and partwise disjunct isochrones for quite low resolutions - which is far from the historical ORS-isochrones.

Attention:  The server in use `http://router.project-osrm.org/` is not very stable

```
options(osrm.server = "http://router.project-osrm.org/", osrm.profile = "driving") 

isochrone_osrm <- osrm::osrmIsochrone(loc = coords, breaks = c(0,11), res = 150)
leaflet() %>% 
  addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.TonerLite, group = "Toner Lite") %>% 
  addPolygons(data = isochrone_osrm)
```

[image]

Do any of you have an idea on how to reproduce the historical isochrones in a better way? Are there more suitable packages or API's?